# Explanation on on object literal in java script

Tags: javascript, html

Why can't we access the second item in the object literal in the same way as in first.

```
var foo = {a:"alpha",2:"beta"};
console.log(foo.a) -> printing 'alpha' absolutely right
console.log(foo.2) -> Error: missing ) after argument list
```

Why does we have two different behavior ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable/field names (known as identifiers) cannot start with a number in Javascript. So `2` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @elclanrs It can be IN an object, but it can't be an identifier still, so you can't do `a.2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking that it has something to do with the position.

Answer (score 1):

A variable cannot start with a numer

You can have invalid characters in your variable name if you do the following:

```
var a={"2":33}
console.log(a["2"]);
```